# How to make the view of a UIViewController to stick to the bottom of it's superview?

Tags: iphone

Programmatically, and not with using xib files? UIView's autoresizingMask is not really the right thing, I think. Since it's not about resizing but laying out. I couldn't find layout masks. But Interface Builder seems to allow to attach a view to top, left, right, center or bottom. So there must be a mechanism.

Answer (score 6):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622559-autoresizingmask

```
[view setAutoresizingMask: UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin];
```